# What is Thanksgiving in Latin?

Tags: word-request, calendarium

It is now Thanksgiving in the US.
How can I translate the name of the event to Latin?
The [Vicipaedia page](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festum_Gratias_Agendi) is marked dubious (and I am suspicious of the Latin Wikipedia in any case).
It offers several translations, but there are no references or justification.

Two kinds of reasoning come to mind:
One could either try to form a festival name in Roman style, or one could look for Latin mentions of Thanksgiving.
I assume someone very fluent in Latin has at least mentioned Thanksgiving, and perhaps there is even a canonical translation.

To reiterate, I am looking for a Latin translation of "Thanksgiving" with references or justification.
It is easy enough to coin ideas like *Festum Gratias Agendi* (see more on Wikipedia); the goal is to find support for a translation.